# How do I cd in to the directory made by tar?

Tags: bash

Given the following command:
`curl http://anysite.com/tarball.tar.gz | tar xz`
How do I cd in to the directory made by `tar`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that command, and without being able to trust that you did this in an empty working directory, the answer is, "**You don't.**". Tarballs may have any number of files or directories, named anything, at their root level.

An alternative might be something like this:

```
mkdir temp && curl http://anysite.com/tarball.tar.gz | tar xzC temp && cd temp && cd *
```

That way you're making a new directory, telling `tar` to extract the tarball into it, and then `cd`ing into it. That last `cd *` will work if the tarball contained only a single top-level item, and it was a directory. *Edit: It will also "work" if the first item the `*` matches in your temp directory a directory, even if there are other directories or files that came out of the top level of the tarball. This may not be the definition of "work" that you're looking for.* If the first item the `*` matches is not a directory, you'll get an error for that part of the command.

Comment: Ah, great, this is what I was looking for. I'm working with tarballs that only have a single top level directory and somehow just assumed all tarballs were the same. Obviously not. Thanks!

Comment: I think that command will still work for you, but I accidentally misstated what the `cd *` might do. I'm about to edit my Answer to fix it.